# XNA Subtract blending function doesn't work

Tags: xna-4.0, blending

I wanted to subtract a white image with black circle background from a picture to get a lighting circle here is the white image
[image: White Background and Black Circle]
So I wrote this code

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, new BlendState
{
      ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Subtract,
      AlphaBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Subtract
});
//Draw the white image with black circle
spriteBatch.Draw(test, new Vector2(), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

I was aiming to get difference between it and the background image rendered
[image]
to get something like this
[image]

But the result that the first image is only drawn while second is below it

Comment: Couldn't you simply do this with alpha blending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposing my answer from [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23783/8119).

[image]

Just set the below as the BlendState in SpriteBatch.Begin(). Also worth noting is that if the SortMode is SpriteSortMode.Immediate you can alter the all of the GraphicsDevice's properties without calling Spritebatch.Begin again.

```
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = new BlendState {

            ColorSourceBlend = Blend.Zero,
            ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceColor,

            AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.Zero,
            AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceColor

        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try inverting the image, in substraction what happens is that (for every channel (RGB) of every pixel) the following calculation is done: result = clip( source - filter, 0, 255 ).

With filter the white image you posted. Meaning that the white parts of the source becoming black, and the black parts staying the same.

Comment: what do u mean? making the source is the destination and destination is the source ??